# Определение дня "Завтра", "Послезавтра" из даты

Tags: java, дата, время

Нужен метод, которому на вход поступает дата и время какого-то события, он сравнивает ее с текущей и говорит: "Событие произойдет завтра/послезавтра/вчера/через час"

Подобное есть уже на Vk.com ("Заходил 15 минут назад").

Кто-нибудь уже делал подобное? Есть какие-нибудь гайды как это сделать лаконично?)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Лаконично? Забудьте! Для начала, вам придётся делать различие между «12 минут назад», «22 минут**ы** назад» и «1 минут**у** назад». Думаете, за вас это сделает язык? Руками, всё руками.

Comment: @VladD Что касательно чистой Java, есть готовые библиотеки, вроде [ICU](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14327683). А в Android, к примеру, [встроенный в SDK механизм присутствует](http://www.dimasokol.ru/plurals-in-android/). Так что не так уж что прям "все руками".

Comment: Cсылка по вопросу на [EnSO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859288/how-to-calculate-time-ago-in-java)

Comment: @pavlofff: Ну да, существуют библиотеки для форм множественного числа, но это лишь первый шаг. Для начала нужно строго определить логику, а потом взять и тупо реализовать её. Никакой магии нет, чистая работа. «Вчера»? «Неделю назад»? «В прошлый четверг»? «На Пасху»? Все правила нужно специфицировать самому. Готового набора быть не может, потому что у каждого свои требования. Например, если это клиент онлайн-магазина, то может быть интересен опорный пункт «со дня вашего последнего посещения».

Comment: @pavlofff: Ну и подключать достаточно громоздкую ICU имеет смысл, если нужна поддержка нескольких языков. Если всё ограничивается русским, проще закодировать руками.

Answer (score 1):

Может человек просто не знает как получить разницу во времени между двумя dete в разных временных интервалах (днях, часах...)

Если старая версия java 7 и ниже, то используйте `jodatime`. Там много методов для расчётов с датой и временем. Вот так например можно посчитать сколько дней до события.

```
Date event = ...;
Date now = ...;

// перейти в jodatime
LocalDate localEvent = new LocalDate(event);
LocalDate localNow = new LocalDate(now);

Days days = Days.daysBetween(localNow, localEvent);
int d = days.getDays(); // сколько дней до события
```

Прямо калька с официального FAQ
Так же найдутся методы для расчёта количества часов, минут, и т.д.

```
if (d == -1) {
    System.out.println("Вчера");
} else if (d == 1) {
    System.out.println("Завтра");
} else if (d == 2) {
    System.out.println("Послезавтра");
} else if (d > 0) {
    System.out.printf("Через %d дня\n", d);
} else if (d == 0) {
    // подсчитать часы. только потребуется перевод в LocalDateTime или LocalTime
}
```

В новой java 8 вроде многое позаимствовано из jodatime.

Вот ещё что. LocalData из jodatime берёт в расчёт timezone и new LocalDate(date) может отличаться от date (+|- день). Тогда можно воспользоваться методом LocalDate.fromDateFields(Date date)

```
LocalDate local = LocalDate.fromDateFields(date)
```

Тогда timezone игнорируется, local будет показывать точно такое же день как date.

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю, что определенной разнице во времени между текущим временем и датой и между указанными в каком-то событии сопоставляются некие промежутки временного разрыва, которым соответствует определенная фраза или же просто вывод даты события и тд.