# Как форматировать полученную дату и сравнить её?

Tags: java, android, дата, timestamp

Получаю строку даты с сервера в таком формате: `2019-04-11 02:43:40`

Как можно сравнить полученную дату с сервера, с текущей датой и временем и в итоге показывать в приложении в формате: `6 минут назад`  или `8 часов назад` ?

**P.S:** На сервер записывается дата в часовом поясе по Москве. (GMT+3)

**P.P.S:** Предполагаю, что нужно сначала получать дату с устройства "в часовом поясе устройства", например: `2019-04-11 02:45:00 GMT+4` , а вот далее что делать =  не пойму.. или есть готовые библиотеки, которые умеют это делать??

И если моё предположение неверно, то поправьте меня))

**UPDATE**

Не могу получить московское время, используя Joda-time библиотеку:

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Moscow");
DateTime nowMOSCOW = DateTime.now(timeZone);
```

получаю в логах:

```
I/System.out: SSS: 2019-04-10T23:01:55.869+03:00
```

Не совсем понятно, библиотека и этот код как-то зависит от времени на устройстве? Или независимо от того, сколько времени установлено у меня на устройстве и в каком я часовом поясе, я должен получить Московское время??

Comment: Насчет готовых библиотек, возможно есть. А на текущий момент могу предложить использование [SimpleDateFormat](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/parsing-formatting-dates.html) Приводите к нужному виду саму дату. А время `6 минут назад` получаете через `System.currentTimeMillis()-дата поста или что у вас`

Comment: не знаю самый ли это оптимальный вариант, но можно использовать [библиотеку jodatime](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) так, как в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510275/177345). Для склонения (как 1 минута, 2 минуты и тд.) [использовать plurals](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430662/177345)/ Может кто то предложит вариант получше

Comment: еще [варианты решений](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859288/how-to-calculate-time-ago-in-java)

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        long minAgo = (new Date().getTime() - format.parse(date).getTime())/60000; Может я чего не понял, но этот код позволит получить разницу в минутах. дальше выводите,как хотите...

Comment: Используйте возможности java.time

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець в андроид  поддержка java 8 ограничена. в частности java.time доступен с API 26, что фактически равно ее отсутствию

Comment: Дату передавать строкой плохая практика, ну разве только для отображения на фронтенде как есть. Куда проще и правильней работать с числовым UTC представлением